interval not getting cleared in react
I have this problem where my intervals are not getting removed. When the intervalActive prop from its parent gets changed to false, it should run the function stopPagination, but instead it doesnt. The interval keeps going and it does not stop. Does anybody maybe know what is up with this?
   const startPagination = () => {
        if (!intervalId && intervalActive) {
            const id = setInterval(() => {
                paginate(1);
            }, interval[1] * 1000);
            setIntervalId(id);
        }
    };


    const stopPagination = () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        setIntervalId(null);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(intervalActive)
        if (intervalActive) {
            startPagination();
            return () => {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                setIntervalId(null);
            };
        } else {
            stopPagination();
        }
    }, [intervalActive]);

I tried clearing all intervals, but that did not work and removing the clean up function inside the useEffect creates 2 intervals, one that can be removed and added and another one that I don't know about.

useEffect(() => {
    if (interval[0]) {
        let intervalId;
        if (intervalActive) {
            intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                paginate(1);
            }, interval[1] * 1000);
        }

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, [intervalActive, interval]);


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Maybe not a direct answer to your question, but I solve this kind of confusing interval mess by just using setTimeout
const nextPage = () => {
    // your paging code here

    // check if we should call the next page again
    if (intervalActive) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            nextPage();
        }, 1000);
    }
};


thanks but it fixed it already, how do i stop my question?
